# JTable rows count has default value (4 rows) ONLY

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

I have been developing small program in java, i made jtable and connect it to mysql, but it only shows 4 rows only no matter how big my data is...[here is jtable in java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqtmi.jpg)

[and here is mysql table data..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhPux.jpg)

```
con = DBconnect.connect();
    String[] columnNames = {"Name", "UserName", "UserType"};
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);

    jTable1.setModel(model);

    jTable1.setShowGrid(false);
    try {
        PreparedStatement pst;
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from courses");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i <= columns; i++){
            if (rs.next()) {
                uname = rs.getString("C_ID");
                email = rs.getString("C_NAME");
                pass = rs.getString("C_TYPE");
                model.addRow(new Object[]{uname, email, pass});
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing columns and rows, `for(i = 0; i <= columns; i++)` will only read 4 records/rows (because you have 3 columns) .

Simply browse the resultset with `while(rs.next())` to get all the data :

```
   while(rs.next()){

            uname = rs.getString("C_ID");
            email = rs.getString("C_NAME");
            pass = rs.getString("C_TYPE");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{uname, email, pass});

    }
```